# Reflection + function pointers vs Observer pattern

Tags: c++, dll, reflection, observer-pattern

I have got a program which gets commands via network and allocates these to a specific function. And now I want to implement a plugin feature where I can add a .dll file in a folder. The next step is to invoke the methods in the dll based on the command.

I have two ideas how to solve this problem but I do not know which of these is better/more performant:

1. Initializing all methods + commands from the dll with reflection and store them in a `std::map<std::string, void(*func)(args...)>`. When the program receives a command it looks up the associated function in the map and invokes it.
2. Load the dll into runtime and create an interface which hands over the `std::string` with the arguments to all dll's which have implemented it. The method in the dll uses `if` statements to check the command can be processed in there. (Observer pattern)

If there are better options which I have not mentioned let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are using incorrect terminology to describe what you want, I would say option 2 is "cleaner"

Forcing a singular interface that is implemented by plug-in DLLs is the best-practice way of establishing the sort of dependency injection you're seeking, in my opinion.

Comment: What terminology is incorrect, so I can edit my question? Is option 2 also more performent or is it just "cleaner"?